# How to write lambda expression to extract information from a column data

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq

I am trying to extract data from a column and apply filter for the same. Below is the scenario.

As shown in below screenshot, a `serviceId` can have multiple `userRoleId` assigned to it. 0 or more `userRoleId` are stored in a single column `userRoleIds` as string value. I am trying to write a lambda expression to filter information when I select one or more `userRoleId`.

[image]

Let's say, if I pass user id 1,4,11,9 as a list, then it should return the following rows:

[image]

Could you please share code snippet to achieve this in a single query without duplication records. Thanks in advance.

Tried to implement the logic with SQL UDFs. Was able to achieve it. But required to do it from LINQ lambda expression.

Comment: It's a **lambda** expression - yes "b" before "d" - not a "lamda" ......

Comment: Show model, sample filter. LINQ expression is written from classes not images.

Comment: What LINQ are you using: LINQ to Objects / SQL / EF 6.x / EF Core 2.0 / 2.1 / 3.x / 5.x / 6.x? What database provider? C# is a language of types - what are the types involved?

Comment: Also, what is the actual (C#) value in `userRoleIds` for record 3?

Comment: I’m using .NET 4.8 with EF6. The actual value for userRoleIds for record 3 is NULL.

Comment: The real solution is to fix your DB schema.   You don't want to have a string field with json data of your related fields, you want to have a table of values to join to.  That's the idiomatic solution in SQL, and it's what the language and the tools based off of it are optimized for.  Doing this is just making things really hard on yourself

Comment: I agree. Let me try it out.

Answer (score 0):

Try following :

```
            int[] values = { 1, 4, 11, 9 };
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("serviceId", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("userRoleIds", typeof(int[]));

            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 1, new int[] { 1,5,11}});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 2, new int[] {4} });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 3, null });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 4, new int[] { 1, 4, 6, 9, 19 } });

            var results = dt.AsEnumerable().Where(x => x.Field<object>("userRoleIds") != null && x.Field<int[]>("userRoleIds").Any(y => values.Contains(y))).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [LINQKit](https://github.com/scottksmith95/LINQKit), you can create helpers to allow taking a `List<T>` of possible members of a delimited string and searching it in an EF/EF Core compatible way by adding a predicate for each term that is like `v == term || v.StartsWith(term + delimiter) || v.EndsWith(delimiter + term) || v.Contains(delimiter + term + delimiter)`.

You can also avoid LINQKit by rolling your own `Expression` tree helpers.

Here is code I use with a LINQKit dependency:

```
public static class LinqKitExt { // using LINQKit
    // string fieldExpr(T row) - function returning multiple value delimited string field to test
    // delimiter - string separator between values in test field
    // value - string value to find in splits of test field
    // r => fieldExpr(r).Split(delimiter).Contains(value)
    public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> SplitContains<T>(this Expression<Func<T, string>> fieldExpr, string delimiter, string value) {
        var pred = PredicateBuilder.New<T>(r => fieldExpr.Invoke(r) == value);
        pred = pred.Or(r => fieldExpr.Invoke(r).StartsWith(value + delimiter));
        pred = pred.Or(r => fieldExpr.Invoke(r).EndsWith(delimiter + value));
        pred = pred.Or(r => fieldExpr.Invoke(r).Contains(delimiter + value + delimiter));

        return pred;
    }

    // values - string values, one of which to find in splits of test field
    // string fieldExpr(T row) - function returning multiple value delimited string field to test
    // delimiter - string separator between values in test field
    // r => values.Any(value => fieldExpr(r).Split(delimiter).Contains(value))
    public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> SplitContainsAny<T>(this IEnumerable<string> values, Expression<Func<T, string>> fieldExpr, string delimiter) {
        var pred = PredicateBuilder.New<T>();
        foreach (var value in values)
            pred = pred.Or(fieldExpr.SplitContains(delimiter, value));

        return pred;
    }
    // values - string values, one of which to find in splits of test field
    // string fieldExpr(T row) - function returning multiple value delimited string field to test
    // delimiter - string separator between values in test field
    // dbq.Where(r => values.Any(value => fieldExpr(r).Split(delimiter).Contains(value)))
    public static IQueryable<T> WhereSplitContainsAny<T>(this IQueryable<T> dbq, Expression<Func<T, string>> fieldExpr, string delimiter, IEnumerable<string> values) =>
        dbq.AsExpandable().Where(values.SplitContainsAny(fieldExpr, delimiter));
}
```

With this available, you can do:

```
var ans = src.WhereSplitContainsAny(s => s.userRoleIds.Substring(1, s.userRoleIds.Length-2),
                                    ",",
                                    filter.Select(n => n.ToString()))
             .ToList();
```